# How to get Salesforce Security token without refreshing it

Tags: security-token, refresh-token

I want to get the Salesforce security token without refreshing or resetting it.

`/lightning/settings/personal/ResetApiToken/home`

I do have the option to Reset it but other users might be using it.

Comment: The edit you suggested on *sfdcfox*'s answer should either be: A) added as a comment to his answer, or B) added as a separate answer if it is, indeed, another solution that would be considered to be an answer.  (It is encouraged on SFSE to answer your own question if you come up with a solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't retrieve a security token or password for any user from Salesforce, as a matter of security. You'll have to reset it, or get it from somewhere else. Note that even *salesforce.com technical support* or *Research & Development* can get these items back, as they are passed through a one-way hash that is impossible to recover the data from.

Comment: You just have to either give others a "Heads up!" that you need to reset it, get it from one of them if they have it saved somewhere, or just reset it and let them figure it out. (I suggest one of the first two.)

Answer (score 0):

There can be another solution if you like me are not able to reach out to all the developers working on same solution.
Add your IP as a trusted IP.
[image]

[image]

I tried it with my Postman and if postman is in the cloud, the request comes from there and it works. You won't need to concatenate the security token with the Password.